# Text editor in J2ME - Store text in memory to edit

Tags: java, java-me, text-editor

I'm developing a text editor in J2ME for editing source code, and because it has special features like syntax coloring, I can't use the regular TextBox, so I have to make a text box from scratch, using Canvas.

I found the way of reading/writing files from/to memory card, using FileConnection and the InputStreamReader/OutputStreamWriter classes for read and write text.

Now the problem is, when I read the file, how I can store the read information in memory, in order to edit the text freely and decide later if I can save or discard the changes?

Do I create a temporary file where I store the data for editing? But how can I write/delete text in middle of the file? Or do I have to dump the data in a StringBuffer?

Any methods or alternatives will be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Give me the source code of how you read/write wiles ;D

Comment: Read about the FileConnection API. This is an example: http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-access-local-file-systems-from-j2me-devices-using-fileconnectio-2.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use `String` (for storing the whole text in one variable)
or `Vector` of `String`s (for storing the text line by line).

Temporary files is a very bad solution.